# How MeController constractor calls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

When I create default SPA template progect VS2013 creates **MeController**. Calling Get I have a user information. But when I create almost the same Controller, for example UserController, and copy-paste all from Me to User I do not have necessary info about user on breakpoint in the method:

```
// GET api/Me
public GetViewModel Get()
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    return new GetViewModel() { Hometown = user.Hometown };
}
```

I don't uderstand this magic! I also do not see a caller of constractor and sender of *userManager*. Where is it?

```
public MeController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a default constructor in the MeController which gets called by default. In this case the *UserManager*, is got from the Owin contect as below

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Even if you copy this over to a new class like UserController, this should happen. Are you using any DI library like StrucuteMap/Unity etc? Certain DI controllers choose the 'greediest' constructor(the one with the maximum arguments). You could override that by using appropriate methods for that DI library(like [this](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/08/choosing-the-constructor-function-in-structuremap-without-attributes/) if you are using StructureMap)

In case you would want to use your own UserManager you could use your own implementation of UserManager and have it used. But if you are planning to stick with the default, this is already added in Startup.Auth.cs into the Owin pipeline.